# Confuse about DOM manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, dom

I want use `+new Date` to compute a DOM manipulation time cost in javascript, like insert 240,000  DOM nodes

```
var t1 = +new Date();

var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var t = 0; t < 6; t++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + "," + t));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

var t2 = +new Date();
console.log(t2 - t1);
```

when I run this code, the log show only about 1 second, but it actually cost more than 1 second, even more than 5 seconds

Why this happened? How can I compute this correct cost time?

Comment: If you're trying to test performance check out http://jsperf.com/

Comment: @elclanrs: No, I just want to know why my code doesn't work, and how can I let it work

Comment: You're measuring the time that code took correctly. The other four seconds must be either before it, or after it (the browser rendering the result). Side note: If your goal is speed, you're probably better off building the structure outside the DOM (in a `DocumentFragment` or just a disconnected `table`) and then appending it all at once when you're done. For instance, [this](http://jsbin.com/oxosin/2) is dramatically faster than [this](http://jsbin.com/oxosin/1) in terms of the table actually appearing.

Comment: You're measuring the time it takes to execute the code. In this extreme scenario the bottleneck is for the browser to carry out the task of showing the massive chunk of DOM nodes. You're accurately measuring the time it took to dispatch those thousands of appends.

Comment: DOM changes can be delayed by the browser until the end of a function. Try to log the times before calling the dom insertions function and after the function call has been returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly measuring the time it takes for that snippet of Javascript to run, however the browser has to do a lot of work to render the result.

If you set a timeout, you can let the browser render before completing the measurement:

```
var t1 = new Date();

var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var t = 0; t < 6; t++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + "," + t));
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}

console.log("Script finished: ", new Date() - t1);
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Render complete: ", new Date() - t1);
});
```

Comment: The browser event loop lets currently running scripts execute before redrawing the page. The setTimeout effectively schedules a new code block to run *after* the pending paint changes. Also, if it works or this was helpful, please upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: So setTimeout without a value, provides the browser enough time to complete its render and then display the time taken?

Comment: saying "enough time" is misleading. Javascript blocks rendering while it's executing. The 'setTimeout' effectively creates a script that will execute after the re-render, whenever that may be. It's not a matter of 'enough time', but of what is in the queue to be executed.